# extract data from a dictionary returned by pycurl

Tags: python, dictionary, pycurl

I have this:

```
import pycurl
import pprint
import json

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://mydomainname.com')

c.perform()
```

the above code return a dictionary like this:

```
{"name":"steve", "lastvisit":"10-02-2012", "age":12}
```

I want to loop through that dictionary and get just the age:

```
age : 12
```

I tried:

```
diction = {}
diction = c.perform()
pprint.pprint(diction["age"])
```

No data returned and I got this error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable
```

Comment: Thank you Metijn!! any idea how to get the age?

Comment: I am presuming you are using Python 3 (judging by the exception, python 3.1 or 3.2).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`c.perform()` doesn't return anything, you need to configure a file-like object to capture the value. A [`BytesIO` object](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) would do, you can then call [`.getvalue()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO.getvalue) on that after the call completes:

```
import pycurl
import pprint
import json
from io import BytesIO

c = pycurl.Curl()
data = BytesIO()

c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://mydomainname.com')
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, data.write)
c.perform()

dictionary = json.loads(data.getvalue())
pprint.pprint(dictionary["age"])
```

If you are not married to `pycurl`, you might find [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) to be a lot easier:

```
import pprint
import requests

dictionary = requests.get('https://mydomainname.com').json()
pprint.pprint(dictionary["age"])
```

Even the standard library [`urllib.request` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) will be easier than using `pycurl`:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pprint
import json

response = urlopen('https://mydomainname.com')
dictionary = json.load(response)
pprint.pprint(dictionary["age"])
```

Comment: Thank you very much Metijn, I tried the code and I got this error: `AttributeError: getvalue`

Comment: @mongotop: Apologies, I didn't read the [documentation](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/curlobject.html) in enough detail. Why are you using `pycurl`? Why not use a more convenient library?

Comment: To be honest that is the one I know about, can you please suggest another library.

Comment: Your code works like a charm!!!! I'm reading now about requests. Thank you very much for educating me!!!! highly appreciated!!!

Comment: @MartijnPieters is it possible to use `requests` to imitate `curl 'some_url' -d 'some_json'`? I couldn't find a way to do that.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: you mean `requests.post('some_url', json=python_object)`? It'll set the right headers and encode the Python structure to JSON for you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. I'm actually trying to query an *elastic search* server, by `data=my_json` it's giving an error, I think it's because `'`s instead of `"`s from `json.loads`. I'll be grateful if you can enlighten me on this.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: that'd be a new question or the chat room, not the comments here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters 'use requests instead' isn't an answer to this problem. it performs extremely badly with large responses, so for me, the only option is to use pycurl.

Comment: @Strobe_: Do read the other comments, where the OP is asking for recommendations. As for large responses: have you tried streaming the response?